# Success dialog after user shared

Tags: android, android-intent

This is a question of many. How to get callback if the user shared intent(facebook or twitter)?

Or there is an alternative way to do it?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.google.fr/");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
```

startActivityForResult() seems not working...

Comment: Share your detail code about this .

Comment: You will only able to get, something has been shared. But where? You cannot get.

Comment: @Dhruv what do you mean?

Comment: You cannot get where (in which app) user has shared your text..

Comment: assuming the user shared on facebook... how to get callback if the user shared or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To request callback,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.google.fr/");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"), 101);
```

You will receive callback in,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 101){
        //your stuff here
    }
}
```

Note : You will receive callback in `Activity` only in case you have `Fragment`.

Comment: yes i received that request code, but what i want is the result code telling that the user shared or not...

Comment: In your case, onActivityResult will also called if user press back button without sharing content...

Comment: back button and post button result code are 0. how can I identify if user shared or not..

Comment: First, we have to use requestCode not resultCode. And I'm trying to say that, you will get same requestCode for both operation (while pressing back button and sharing). So you **cannot** identify whether the user has shared or not.